# might help to test or might help test

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

This script is for testing purposes only.  You need to modify it using the new service data.  Also, the following procedure might help **(to test \ test)** the data and understand how the system works.

I wonder whether I should write might help to test or might help test.  help is usually used with "to", and we don't usually write "help testing".  Therefore the sentence without might should be "help to test" and "might" will not change it.
On the other hand, if it should be "help testing", then "might" will modify it to be "might help test".

**Is this a right analysis? Should it be "might help to test"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both choices are correct and idiomatic.

It's a question of whether you prefer to use a **to-infinitive** or a **bare infinitive**.

So you might well hear people say:

> Please help the old lady climb the stairs

(bare infinitive)

or

> Please help the old lady to climb the stairs

(to-infinitive).

It's simply a question of preference.

https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/

https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/infin2.htm